# Is there a formula for the inverse of a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f$ with the derivative $f'$ is there a general formula to deduce $(f')^{-1}$ provided it exists?

Comment: derivative of the legendre transform technically satisfies this I think?

Comment: Is it Integration operator ? I guess.

Comment: I actually ask to explicitly calculate the legendre transform.

Comment: There's no general formula for the inverse of $f$, why should there be one for the inverse of $f'$?

Comment: I am fine with a result dependent on $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $f(x)=e^{e^x}$. We have that $f^{-1}=\ln(\ln(x))$. If there were a formula for $(f')^{-1}$, then it would be an elementary function. However, $f'(x)=e^{e^x+x}$, whose inverse is not an elementary function. In fact, its inverse is $(f')^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)-W(x)$, where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), defined to be the inverse of $xe^x$. This function is known not to be elementary, and thus $(f')^{-1}=\ln(x)-W(x)$ is not elementary.